# What was this (novel or short) story about travel between parallel/multiple universes by tuning into them like a radio?

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

Many years ago I read a story about multiple universes splitting apart, and the possibility to trade between them using a radio like scanner to find where you left from.

It may be a short story or a novel, or a collection of stories. I'm not sure. 
The main character ended up with quite different lives, including different wives and different careers.

Probably published around the early to mid 1980s.

Comment: You will have to add more details to this. E.g. how many years was "years ago", was it 2 years or 50? Also, try to add *any* more details from the story as you can to help us narrow down.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "The Quicksilver Screen" by Don H Debrandt

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Can you name some elements or quote a brief passage to demonstrate that this matches OP's question?